# How to get Value from Firebase and add in HTML Table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get loggedin Used Data from firebase and add show into HTML Table
this is my database structure"

```
{
  "attendance": {
    "7-----------asdasdasd-----": {
      "2023-1-9": {
        "status": "success"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

I'm simply tring to get value date and status value from firebase make table in html to show data.
I'm able to login user using firebase auth google. and able to post value aswell. just not able to get value correctly and show in table.
Here is what i tried to get value from firebase and add into html table:

```js
// Get the table element
var table = document.getElementById("attendance-table");

// Handle auth state changes
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref("attendance/" + userId).on("value", function(snapshot) {
      // Clear the table
      table.innerHTML = "";

      // Get the attendance data
      var attendanceData = snapshot.val();
      var attendanceKeys = Object.keys(attendanceData);

      // Add a row to the table for each attendance record
      for (var i = 0; i < attendanceKeys.length; i++) {
        var date = attendanceKeys[i];
        var status = attendanceData[attendanceKeys[i]].status;
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var dateCell = document.createElement("td");
        var statusCell = document.createElement("td");
        dateCell.innerHTML = date;
        statusCell.innerHTML = status;
        row.appendChild(dateCell);
        row.appendChild(statusCell);
        table.appendChild(row);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="attendance-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="attendance-table-body"></tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the Solutions now it Worked!
Here is Script Changes:

```js
<script>
// Get the table element
var table = document.getElementById("attendance-table");

// Handle auth state changes
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref("attendance/" + userId).once("value", function(snapshot) {
      // Clear the table
      table.innerHTML = "";

      // Get the attendance data
      var attendanceData = snapshot.val();
      var attendanceKeys = Object.keys(attendanceData);

      // Add a row to the table for each attendance record
      for (var i = 0; i < attendanceKeys.length; i++) {
        var date = attendanceKeys[i];
        var status = attendanceData[attendanceKeys[i]].status;
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var dateCell = document.createElement("td");
        var statusCell = document.createElement("td");
        dateCell.innerHTML = date;
        statusCell.innerHTML = status;
        row.appendChild(dateCell);
        row.appendChild(statusCell);
        table.appendChild(row);
      }
    });
  }
});

</script>
```